# Convert a matrix into a hash data strucutre

Tags: ruby

i have a matrix like this

```
[
  ["name", "company1", "company2", "company3"], 
  ["hr_admin", "Tom", "Joane", "Kris"], 
  ["manager", "Philip", "Daemon", "Kristy"]
]
```

How can I convert into this data structure?

```
{
  "company1" => {
    "hr_admin"=> "Tom",
    "manager" => "Philip"
  },
  "Company2" => {
    "hr_admin"=> "Joane",
    "manager" => "Daemon"
  },
  "company3" => {
    "hr_admin"=> "Kris",
    "manager" => "Kristy"
  }
}
```

I have tried approach like taking out the first row of matrix (header) and zipping the rest o
f the matrix to change their position. It worked to some extent but it doesnt looks very good. So I am turning up here for help.

Comment: "it doesnt looks very good" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix[0][1...matrix[0].length].each_with_index.map do |x,i| 
    values = matrix[1..matrix.length].map do |x|
        [x[0], x[i+1]]
        end.to_h
    [x, values]
    end.to_h
```

`matrix[0].length` and `matrix.length` could be omittable depending on ruby version.

First you take all elements of first row but first.

then you map them with index to e.g. `[["hr_admin", "Tom"],["manager", "Phil"]]` using the index
then you call `to_h` on every element and on whole array.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
  ["name", "company1", "company2", "company3"], 
  ["hr_admin", "Tom", "Joane", "Kris"], 
  ["manager", "Philip", "Daemon", "Kristy"]
]
```

Each key-value pair of the hash to be constructed is formed from the "columns" of `arr`. It therefore is convenient to compute the transpose of `arr`:

```
(_, *positions), *by_company = arr.transpose
  #=> [["name", "hr_admin", "manager"],
  #    ["company1", "Tom", "Philip"],
  #    ["company2", "Joane", "Daemon"],
  #    ["company3", "Kris", "Kristy"]]
```

I made use of Ruby's [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) (a.k.a *array destructuring*) feature (see [this blog](https://riptutorial.com/ruby/example/8798/decomposition) for elabortion) to assign different parts of the inverse of `arr` to variables. Those values are as follows<sup>1</sup>.

```
_ #=> "name"   
positions
  #=> ["hr_admin", "manager"]
by_company
  #=> [["company1", "Tom", "Philip"],
  #    ["company2", "Joane", "Daemon"],
  #    ["company3", "Kris", "Kristy"]]
```

It is now a simple matter to form the desired hash. Once again I will use array decomposition to advantage.

```
by_company.each_with_object({}) do |(company_name, *employees),h|
  h[company_name] = positions.zip(employees).to_h
end
  #=> {"company1"=>{"hr_admin"=>"Tom", "manager"=>"Philip"},
  #    "company2"=>{"hr_admin"=>"Joane", "manager"=>"Daemon"},
  #    "company3"=>{"hr_admin"=>"Kris", "manager"=>"Kristy"}}
```

When, for example,

```
company_name, *employees = ["company1", "Tom", "Philip"]
company_name
  #=> "company1"
employees
  #=> ["Tom", "Philip"]
```

so

```
h[company_name] = positions.zip(employees).to_h
h["company1"]   = ["hr_admin", "manager"].zip(["Tom", "Philip"]).to_h
                = [["hr_admin", "Tom"], ["manager", "Philip"]].to_h
                = {"hr_admin"=>"Tom", "manager"=>"Philip"}
```

Note that these calculations do not depend on the numbers of rows or columns of `arr`.

<sup>1. As is common practice, I used the special variable `_` to signal to the reader that its value is not used in subsequent calculations.</sup>